# Access method of a Vue component by it's string name

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I've a list of Vue objects like this:

> vue_objectname0,
>
> vue_objectname1,
>
> vue_objectname2  etc...

these object rae created by:

```
var vue_objectname0 = new Vue({
  el: '#vue_objectname0',
  data: {
    seen: true,
  }
})
```

from browser console I can correctly access data with:

```
vue_objectname0.seen
```

now I need to access the same data from a string as name of the object, how can I convert the string to the Object?

```
var name = "vue_objectname"+number;
console.log(name.seen);
```

this return "undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All global variable can be accessed using the `window` object as well.

`window["vue_objectname"+number]`